# I created a generator of students in rails and I cant populate it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

Here is my code: I created a task named setup on dev enviroment to populate the sqlite3 table.

```
task setup: :environment do
    puts "Cadastrando os alunos..."

    100.times do |i|
      Aluno.create!(
        inscricao: Faker::Lorem,
        data_inscricao: Faker::Date,
        nome: Faker::Name,
        data_nascimento: Faker::Date,
        cpf: Faker::Base.numerify('###.###.###-##'),
        endereco: Faker::Lorem,
        cidade: Faker::Lorem,
        bairro: Faker::Lorem,
        cep: Faker::Base.numerify('#####-###'),
        contato1: Faker::Base.numerify('(##) #####-####'),
        contato2: Faker::Base.numerify('(##) #####-####'),
        email: Faker::Internet.email,
        facebook: Faker::Lorem,
        igreja: Faker::Lorem,
        soube: Faker::Lorem,
        proposito: Faker::Lorem,
        historico: Faker::Lorem
      )
    end
  end
```

and here is the error.

[image]

If you need additional information I will provide.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error, it was with Faker::Date attribute!
Thx.